# Role does not exist in postgres in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have set up a AWS EC2 instance to `docker-compose` my `express` and `postgres` backend, I git pulled my project files into the instance and setup all the environment variables and ran docker-compose up. The server successfully started but the database couldn't get initialized due to this error: `Detail: Role "user" does not exist.`. Everything worked properly when I docker-composed locally on my machine. I did setup `postgres` and created role `user` with the corresponding `password` in the instance

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  type:
    container_name: type-backend
    image: type:latest
    restart: on-failure
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
      NODE_ENV: production
      PORT: 4000
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - app-data:/type

  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: type-database
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "35432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: type-prod
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  app-data:
  db-data:
```

**data-source.ts**

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { User } from './entities/user';
import { Test } from './entities/test';
import { migration1684564075219 } from './migrations/1684564075219-migration';

dotenv.config();

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'database',
  port: 5432,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  logging: true,
  synchronize: false,
  cache: false,
  entities: [Test, User],
  migrations: [migration1684564075219],
});

AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Data Source has been initialized!');
    AppDataSource.runMigrations();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error during Data Source initialization', err);
  });
```

**index.ts**

```
const main = async () => {
  const app = express();
  app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
  });
  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [TestResolver, UserResolver],
      validate: false,
    }),
    persistedQueries: false,
    introspection: false,
    context: () => ({ em: AppDataSource.manager }),
  });

  await apolloServer.start();
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });
};

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

**.env.example**

```
DATABASE_USERNAME="user"
DATABASE_PASSWORD="pass"
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/db"
DATABASE_NAME="db"
PORT=4000
```

Comment: What is the output within `psql` of the command `\du` ? Does it show the user "user"?

Comment: Yes and it’s got super user privileges